# What is this mode and how do i get out of it?

Tags: interface

Was following blender guru's tutorial(Part 7 lvl 1) to split the screen,and when i joined the split i accidentally joined this view to my colored view.Now i can't get out of this view.When i render the image ,it stills show colour previously used.

[image]

Comment: Did you try out the three balls in the top right corner of the view? The change the rendering mode in the viewport

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about Rendered View. Just click the button I marked in the screenshot.

[Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/display/shading.html#bpy-types-view3dshading-type) is some more information on what these four buttons do.

[image]

I hope this helps.